# Plotting pandas dataframe with microseconds resolution

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to use python matplotlib to plot a pandas DataFrame.  The DataFrame has a 'time' column and a 'val' column.  The 'time' column is set as index and has resolution up to microseconds.  When I go about plotting it, the values on the x-axis are are totally off (way outside the time range of the data).  What could be wrong?  Any help is appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates

df = pd.read_csv("/tmp/a.csv")
df = df.set_index('time')

def plot1(df):
    ax = df.plot(y='val')
    ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%H%M%S.%f"))
    plt.show()
    return ax

plot1(df)
```

Data in '/tmp/a.csv':

```
time,val
143642.229348,12
143642.250195,53
143642.252341,17
143642.254349,56
143642.311674,31
143642.313758,36
143642.320217,24
143642.339777,86
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to convert your `time` column to `datetime` after reading it from the CSV file:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="%H%M%S.%f")
```

alternatively you can do it on the fly when parsing your CSV file:

```
tm_parser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%H%M%S.%f")

df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/a.csv',
                 sep=',',
                 parse_dates=['time'],
                 date_parser=tm_parser,
                 index_col='time')
```

after that you don't need `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`:

```
In [147]: df.plot()
Out[147]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x8201f60>
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Great, it works perfectly.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Even though it outside the precise scope of this question, it's crucial that the date-time values be formatted as a DatetimeIndex, as accomplished by the `read_csv` argument.  If for some reason you have a series of datetime values in a DataFrame column, use `pd.DatetimeIndex(df.col)`